# Mocking socket acitivity in Python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I've just started working with Python about 3 months ago and I'm currently struggling with using pytest-mock for testing sockets. I was trying to write test using mock to check if the number of calls for socket methods is correct, however I can't make it to work.

How would you recommend starting to write unit test for such method? I couldn't find documentation or stack overflow thread which could help me to understand the problem.

**method to test**

```
def start_server(host, port, key_file, simulator):
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, True)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen()
    while True:
        connection, _ = server_socket.accept()
        # server_thread activity (uses key_file and the simulator variable)
```

Comment: this function will be hard to test because you have a `while` loop with no breaking condition, how will you terminate the test in that case?

Comment: That's exactly the problem I'm facing right now, however the method can't be changed because it's legacy code. I'm C++ developer who was given some legacy python beacuse our company inherited code from the different one and there was no one to write UTs/CICD for it (we've got it with zero UTs and no CI :| )